# How to resolve Windows 10 corrupt user profiles and temporary profiles folders?

Tags: windows-10, user-profile, profile

In my office i had  have configured a windows 10 desktop machine ncomputing thin client remote desktop server  in which there are 20 client machines.

I applied group policy in it for locking control panel settings and mass storage usage so that students cant change wallpaper or other settings.

On two clients suddenly the taskbar and start menu get locked and was not working and desktop icons and taskbar icons was deleted by students.

So on server i moved the profiles to another folder in another D drive so that window will create new profile automatically and new profiles will be created from default and it will recover profile but all the files did not move, and it gave error for ntuser.dat and app folder.

I restarted and then tried to moved and finally when not move i deleted some users folders.

But after restarting, that windows 10 server  started creating temp folder and error came on ncomputing remote desktop clients machines: "we cant sign to your account..,"  and now all clients  taskbar start menu got locked and not opening.

[image: We cant sign in to your account]

When i saw users folder in c drive its created folder named Temp..or temp1 ...temp2 and so on for 20 users and created temporary profile the icons of software on desktop can be clicked from desktop and softwares and my computer all working fine in client machine  but start menu and taskbar is non functional in temporary profile.

i tried to recopy move  back and moved the old profile folder back to user directory but still its creating temp folders for  the old users.

then after google search  i found  some videos and links which told solution for  registry editing  tried all registry fix and `>sfc /scannow`   & `>DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Checkhealth` option but still temp profile is being made and taskbar start menu not working

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

[Microsoft temp profile fix](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-temporary-user-profile-temp-issue/5fbefc7c-0b82-4395-bfda-6d7e2ebeacc6)

[Windows 10  temp profile fix](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/48012-fix-youve-been-signed-temporary-profile-windows-10-a.html)

if some expert   can help me recover any expert advice to make the profile back and functional  then it  will be great helpful to me. Thanking you in advance for giving your precious time and sharing yoru precious knowledge and experience and helping.
waiting for your advices and options.

Comment: You cannot move user profile folders manually like that.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the corrupt profile and put `.old` behind the folder name. Revert you changes and relogin and let windows create a fresh user profile.
Copy the important data back from the renamed `.old` profile

Owh yeah, Windows 10 should not be used a server.

Then the proper way to copy the profile to the D: is

- Press Win + X and select "System."
  In the System window, click on "Advanced system settings" on the left sidebar.
  Under the "Advanced" tab, click the "Settings" button in the "User Profiles" section.
  Select the user profile you want to move and click the "Copy To" button.
  In the "Copy To" window, click the "Browse" button and navigate to the new location on the D: drive where you want to move the profile (e.g., D:\NewProfile).
  Click "OK" to confirm the new location, and then click "OK" again.
- Modify Registry Entries:
  Open the Windows Registry Editor by pressing Win + R, typing regedit, and hitting Enter.
  Navigate to the following registry key:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
  Find the entry that corresponds to the user profile you just moved (look for the "ProfileImagePath" entry that points to the old location on the C: drive).
  Double-click "ProfileImagePath" and change the path to the new location on the D: drive (e.g., D:\NewProfile).
  Click "OK" to save the change.
- Restart Your Computer:
- Log in with the New Profile:
  Log in to the computer using the newly created or moved user profile on the D: drive.

Comment: thanx bro  for ur advice and suggestion firstly  ealier i renamed to user profile folder to user.old it didnt worked windows didnt created new profile then i moved  but now  the  windows is not creating  user profile by itself is therer any hidden registry seeting to force windows to automatically create user profile

Comment: thanx bro again thanx for telling how to move the profile to different drive i did prviously  i forget thanx u made me remember. but now problem is that the current user profile is corrupted and not working. and on above last the windows 10 is not recreating new user profile automatically ....is there any command or registry setting through which windows recreate automatically  new user profile folder instead of temporary folders

Comment: Nope you have to rebuild the profile and copy over the important data

Comment: Ace how to rebuild the profile?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-a-corrupted-user-profile-in-windows-1cf41c18-7ce3-12f9-8e1d-95896661c5c9 @Androidquery